# symfony2 app console: no available command

Tags: symfony

After HDD crash, I had to reimport my symfony2 app into Eclipse from my SVN server.

After syncing everything, I can't use the console anymore. I only get 2 commands : list and help.

I tried:

```
    php bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

At the end, I got the following message:

```
    [InvalidArgumentException]                                
    There are no commands defined in the "assets" namespace.  

    [InvalidArgumentException]                               
    There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.
```

My configuration is pretty simple:
- ubuntu server 11.04 (64bits)
- virtualbox OSE

How can I fix it?

Here is the result of app/console list command:

```
    oc@ubuntu-server:/var/www/projets/Simoov2/src$ app/console list
    Symfony version 2.0.0-RC4 - app/dev/debug

    Usage:
      [options] command [arguments]

    Options:
      --help           -h Display this help message.
      --quiet          -q Do not output any message.
      --verbose        -v Increase verbosity of messages.
      --version        -V Display this program version.
      --ansi              Force ANSI output.
      --no-ansi           Disable ANSI output.
      --no-interaction -n Do not ask any interactive question.
      --shell          -s Launch the shell.
      --env            -e The Environment name.
      --no-debug          Switches off debug mode.

    Available commands:
      help   Displays help for a command
      list   Lists commands
```

Comment: It could not be related with symfony. I created another project, installed symfony2 RC5 and got the same messages... Still investigating...

Comment: I am having the same problems, how did you fix this problem?

Comment: Well, the "projets" folder was mounted within "/var/www" using Virtualbox shared folders system. I don't know if it was related with Virtualbox shared folders or Guest additions but upgrading Virtualbox to 4.1.2 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. As I thought, this is not related to symfony2 but related to virtualbox mounting system.

Comment: and so? can you put me in the right way to solve the same problem? thanks